# Aspnetcore Midlleware not reversed in .net6 when using Graphql

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, graphql, asp.net-core-middleware

In versions before .net6, I used to add an `ErrorHandlerMiddleware` to the pipeline, so I can centralize the need of returning error types in the application with different status codes.
an example is something exactly like this:

```
public class ErrorHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ErrorHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            string responseMessage = error.Message;
            string exceptionMessage;
            object ResponseObject;
            var response = context.Response;
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
            switch (error)
            {
                case ApplicationBadRequestException e:
                    if (e.metaData is { })
                        ResponseObject = new { responseMessage, e.metaData };
                    else ResponseObject = new { responseMessage };
                    response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
                    break;
                case ApplicationNotFoundException e:
                    if (e.metaData is { })
                        ResponseObject = new { responseMessage, e.metaData };
                    else ResponseObject = new { responseMessage };
                    response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
                    break;
                case ApplicationUnAuthorizedException e:
                    responseMessage = "You are not authorized to perform this operation.";
                    ResponseObject = new { responseMessage };
                    response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                    break;
                default:
                    responseMessage = "An error has occurred...Please try again later.";
                    exceptionMessage = getExMessage(error);
                    ResponseObject = new { responseMessage, exceptionMessage };
                    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    break;
            }

            var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(ResponseObject);
            await response.WriteAsync(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Then at any controller in my application, when I need to return a certain error code in the response - for example 400 BadRequest - I do it like so

```
throw new ApplicationBadRequestException("this is the error message");
```

This causes the middleware pipeline to be reversed and this exception is fetched inside the `ErrorhandlerMiddleware`.

Now I am trying to use GraphQL in.net6, when I make this I can see that the Middleware pipeline is NOT reversed and the `ErrorHandlerMiddleware` class is not invoked. why does this happen?
EDIT: I have tried the same scenario with rest apis and the code works perfectly, seems that the problem happens due to the existence of `GraphQL` configuration.

this is my Program.cs file

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var connectionString = builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString"];
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<DBEntities>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()));
builder.Services.AddScoped<DBEntities>(options => options.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<DBEntities>>().CreateDbContext());
builder.Services.AddGraphQLServer().AddQueryType<Query>().AddMutationType<Mutation>()
    .AddProjections().AddFiltering().AddSorting();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlerMiddleware>();

app.MapGraphQL("/graphql");

app.Run();
```

Comment: What happens when you step over `await _next(context)` in your `ErrorHandlerMiddleware`?
I assume there is an actionfilter / exceptionfilter  in the asp.net core mvc pipeline that handles the exception and prevents it to get to your middleware.

Comment: @SanderDeclerck, No there is no such filters in my app, actually I implementing the function that directly throws an exception just to test this scenario.
When I step over it, it is hit only when the app starts up, not after the exception is thrown, and this is exactly my problem.

Comment: As edited, I tried to use the same structure with a standard Rest app in .net6 and everything worked as expected.